# firefox not responding to float with overflow:hidden

Tags: css, firefox, css-float

I have a floated picture with text on right side. I want to set min-width on text, so when the browser is resized, text squeezes but only to certain width. After that it should move under picture. It works in chrome but not in firefox. I do not want to use mediaqueries. Firefox works only if I set width property but that I do not want. Thank you for help.

Code

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="info">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>

        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%
}
.image {
    height:100px;
    width:50px;
    margin:10px;
    border:1px solid;
    float:left
}
.info {
    min-width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/b4ffoayh/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I would know why, but add the code as follows seems to be working.

```
li {
    display:inline-block; /*or inline-table*/
}
```

Updated Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bt0c252z/

Answer (score 0):

i don't know, why you'd like to go for this approach, but the problem seems to be in the fact that your 'info' div gets the entire width of the 1st li tag.

imho, a much easier way to do what you want is to use flexboxes.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background

this probably comes with extra rework, but you could gain more.

Comment: HI, flexbox is great but I need to support older browsers as well

Comment: i don't know your situation, of course, but imho, the need to support the old browsers is a bit exaggerated. it was relevant a couple of years back, but i don't think it is relevant anymore because of the browsers' updates and global internetization (if it can be called like this). just food for thought anyway, but if i were you, i'd think if i really need it.

Comment: Well:), I service an online shop and believe or not, there is a lot of people of all ages (all computer ages as well) entering and buying stuff. Can not afford losing them.

Comment: weeell, i do believe you. :-) just out of curiosity, did you try to look at how many people use old browsers?

Comment: Yes, there is small % of IE7 and IE6 as well. Some of them made a purchase.

Comment: well, good luck with your system :-). just remember that inline-blocks may have a problem of additional white space around them. have a look in here: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/hmlqF